# How do you hide the windows copy dialog box when copying files

Tags: vb.net, file, copy

How do you hide the windows copy dialog box when copying files through vb.net and just use a progress bar in the vb.net form? This is the code I'm using:

```
Public Structure SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    Public hWnd As Integer
    Public wFunc As Integer
    Public pFrom As String
    Public pTo As String
    Public fFlags As Integer
    Public fAborted As Integer
    Public hNameMaps As Integer
    Public sProgress As String
End Structure

Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" (ByRef lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Integer
Private Const FO_COPY As Int32 = &H2
Private Const FO_DELETE As Int32 = &H3
Private Const FO_MOVE As Int32 = &H1

Private Sub Copy()
    Dim shStructure As New SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    Dim currentpath As String = lblShare_Path.Text
    Dim newpath As String = txtBackupLocation.Text
    With shStructure
        .wFunc = FO_COPY
        .pFrom = currentpath
        .pTo = newpath
    End With
    SHFileOperation(shStructure)
End Sub

Private Sub btnBackup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackup.Click
    Copy()

    progbarStatus.Minimum = 0
    progbarStatus.Maximum = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        progbarStatus.Value = i
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `IO.FileStream` to copy file and to get the progress value this way :

```
Dim CF As New IO.FileStream("C:\[Copy From]", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim CT As New IO.FileStream("C:\[Copy To]", IO.FileMode.Create)
Dim len As Long = CF.Length - 1
Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
Dim byteCFead As Integer

While CF.Position < len
    byteCFead = (CF.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))
    CT.Write(buffer, 0, byteCFead)
    ProgressBar.Value = CInt(CF.Position / len * 100)
    Application.DoEvents()
End While

CT.Flush()
CT.Close()
CF.Close()
```

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying that the access to the path was denied.

Comment: Be sure your "Copy From file" is not opened already, and be sure your application have the rights to open the file. To test, start your application as administrator.